# get variable type with static analysis in Python project

Tags: python

I writing a static analyzer tool for Python projects, using Python.

I have the necessity to obtain for each method the type of each variable.

I wrote the following code snippet:

```
def print_var_types(tree):
if tree is None:
    return

if tree.type == "VARIABLE":
    var_name = tree.value
    var_type = type(tree.data_type).__name__
    print(f"{var_name}: {var_type}")

for child in tree.children:
    print_var_types(child)
```

My idea is to transform code read as input in a ast, and then, obtain the type for each variable in each method.

However, Python generates a runtime exception:

```
if tree.type == "VARIABLE":
AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute 'type'
```

My doubt is that considering that Python is weakly typed, is not possible to obtain this information using static analysis. Is correct?

Comment: If you see something like `x = [1, 2, 3]` then sure its possible to know thats gonna be a list of ints. However in the general case you could have that under an `if` and under the else you could have `x = "some string"` which kind of defies static analysis since you have to know if the condition of the if is true at runtime. FYI, modern python style is including type hints more and more these days.

Comment: please format our code correctly, in valid Python. 
Use the \`\`\`  and \`\`\`  quotes instead of the tab-based markup for code: it can make it easier to have the first line properly formatted/